# Call to undefined method Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::startMeasure() Laravel debugbar

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Trying to debug code with Barryvdh\Debugbar. Installed it, everything perfect. Added it to app.php

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class
```

But, when I try to execute

```
\Debugbar::startMeasure();
```

I get error

```
Call to undefined method Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::startMeasure()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: are you using "use DebugBar\DebugBar;" (without quotes) on the top??

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Yes, sry, didn't write about this

Comment: @RossWilson 5.4.22

Comment: 5.4 does not autodiscover packages. Did you add the service provider to your `app.php` as well?

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, please add your answer. I didn't add service provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 does not auto-discover packages and therefore providers need to be manually registered in the configuration.

In your `app.php`:

```
'providers' => [ 
      // Other providers
      Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class
];
```